# Open XML - where did my Prefix Go?

Tags: xml, xsd, openxml

While debugging, the newly created element has its Prefix as w: , but the Xmldoc at the end loses it.

The resultant InnerXML for the Element below is: 
`<altChunk id="FF_HTML" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" />`

Expected Result is `<w:altChunk r:id="FF_HTML"/>`

```
private static XmlDocument prepareHTMLChunks(PackagePart partDocumentXML)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    Stream xmlStream = partDocumentXML.GetStream();
    doc.Load(xmlStream);

    NameTable nt = new NameTable();
    nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);            
    nsManager.AddNamespace("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

    XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//w:bookmarkStart", nsManager);
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
    {
        foreach (XmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes)
        {
            if (attr.Value.EndsWith("HTML"))
            {
                //XmlElement el = doc.CreateElement("w","w:altChunk",string.Empty);
                XmlElement el = doc.CreateElement("altChunk",nsManager.LookupNamespace("w"));


                XmlAttribute altChunkAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("r","id",string.Empty);
                altChunkAttr.Prefix = "r";
                altChunkAttr.Value = attr.Value;
                el.SetAttributeNode(altChunkAttr); 

                XmlNode nodeToReplace = node.ParentNode;                        

                XmlNode bodyNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//w:body", nsManager);
                bodyNode.ReplaceChild(el, nodeToReplace);                          
            }                    
        }
    }            
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: You can go ahead and accept your own answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it :

```
        private static XmlDocument prepareHTMLChunks(PackagePart partDocumentXML)
    {

        XmlDocument _document = new XmlDocument();
        Stream xmlStream = partDocumentXML.GetStream();
        _document.Load(xmlStream);

        XmlNamespaceManager _ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(_document.NameTable);
        _ns.AddNamespace("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

        XmlNode _body = _document.SelectSingleNode("//w:body", _ns);

        foreach (XmlNode _node in _document.SelectNodes("//w:bookmarkStart", _ns))
        {
            foreach (XmlAttribute _attribute in _node.Attributes)
            {
                if (_attribute.Value.EndsWith("HTML"))
                {
                    XmlElement _element = _document.CreateElement("w", "altChunk", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
                    XmlAttribute _newAttr = _document.CreateAttribute("r", "id", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");                        
                    _newAttr.Value = _attribute.Value;
                    _element.Attributes.Append(_newAttr);
                    _body.AppendChild(_element);                        
                }           
            }
        }            
        return _document;       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The prefix is only an alias for the namespace. The prefix itself does not matter. You could use "prefix" as the prefix if you wanted, and it would mean exactly the same thing.

Similarly, the exact same result can come from the xmlns="..." that you show in your question. It means the exact same thing as with the "w:" prefix, assuming that "w" was aliased to the same namespace.

Comment: I understsand your answer John, but how do I get the expected result : <w:altChunk r:id="FF_HTML"/>
and not : <altChunk id="FF_HTML"/>

The problem is that without the prefixes in the XML ,word doesn't open the doc as you might imagine.
Thanks 

Fox

Comment: @Fox: what version of Word are you using, and please post some XML you say will not open without the prefix. I'd be extremely shocked to find that Word doesn't obey basic XML standards that have been in place for over a decade.

Comment: It all lies with the prefixes 

Using Word 2007
My Method above renders the XML Element as <altChunk id="FF_HTML"/>
while Word expects <w:altChunk p:id="FF_HTML"/>. So the only thing I'm trying to figure out is from my method above, how to get the prefixes in the XML when rendering.

Comment: @Fox: I'm hoping you're wrong. If you're right, then Word has a critical bug, and should be immediately fixed.

Comment: Hey John. I actually managed to fix the issue. When inserting the XML, i was missing the schema references..  By doing the following, it all worked out :

                        XmlElement _element = _document.CreateElement("w", "altChunk", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
                        XmlAttribute _newAttr = _document.CreateAttribute("r", "id", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");

Comment: Thanks for your assitance though

Comment: @Fox: experiment: try it with the namespaces, but without the prefixes.